# What are good ways to ask about (famous) open problems?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, etiquette

I understand that asking a question about a famous open problem is viewed as a bit of a red flag and not encouraged, which makes sense of course.

Is there a way to stay within protocol/etiquette while doing this? For example, posting a bounty with the question?

Comment: On this Q+A site, the expectancy is that if you post a Q, you think that it is within reason to get an A for Q in the near future. Q's without A's should be avoided. On the other hand, I'm sure you can come up with lots of Q's about Q's without A's which *do* have A's that are manageable.

Comment: You're going to put a bounty on an open question? This sounds like a waste of reputation points to me. But you are certainly allowed to try it and see what happens.

Comment: You can't post a bounty until the question is at least two days old. In general, bounty changes nothing in the way a question is evaluated.

Comment: @rschwieb Good summary, I think you should expand it to an answer.

Comment: The SE site mathoverflow is your best chance. They occasionally solve obscure open problems. Its usually accidental though.

Comment: @PyR, mathoverflow feels much the same way about famous open problems that mathstackexchange feels. Try posting the Riemann Hypothesis there, and see how quickly it gets closed. What you can try, at m.se or at MO, is asking something like, "What's the latest on the Riemann Hypothesis?" But even for a question like that, you'll get squashed if you don't demonstrate that you have already read extensively on the problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, but occasionally someone will ask about a problem they are facing, it will turn out to be open, but the answerer will solve it. Probably wouldn't happen with famous ones though.

Comment: Here's a [related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19456/how-do-i-ask-an-open-question?rq=1) question.

Comment: Maybe if you can narrow down to some sub-problem that *might* be solvable. Though you do run the risk of coming up with a different problem just as intractable as the famous one.

Comment: By the way, if your question about a famous open problem is "Would someone please check my proof of Goldbach's Conjecture?" then it's pretty much guaranteed to be closed real fast, whether on m.se or on MO.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I cannot help suspecting the user's nom de plume is a clue to what Famous Open Problem would be asked about.

Comment: It isn't actually, @hardmath. Just a bad coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for all these responses, everyone. The question would be of the form of "What are the (main) flaws in this attempt on this part of this particular open question?" Is the consensus that this is not viewed as a reasonable question, either here or on SEoverflow?

Comment: Trav, that is not going to be a reasonable question. Certainly I always vote to close such things, and i do not read the attempt presented.

Comment: I think, in general, if your question is short and self contained (i.e. no long proofs), seeking to learn, and mathematically specific, it can be on topic (and I've seen such questions well-received). However, most posts regarding open problems do not achieve this standard and are poorly received. If you don't have a technical understanding of the open question and related fields, I wouldn't advise asking such questions.

Comment: It seems to me that an open mathematics question will often (typically?) involve many steps, some of which are no longer open.  (For example, the status of the various logical steps of FLT immediately after Ribet established the epsilon conjecture.)  It might be reasonable to post questions about the way some of the established steps were in fact established.

Comment: It _is_ a sub-problem, not the whole conjecture. Picking up on @MiloBrandt's warning "if your question is short and self contained (i.e. no long proofs), seeking to learn, and mathematically specific" (which I think it is) then what counts as a long argument, and what counts as a short argument?

Comment: Look around for the "how to detect crackpots" web pages. They'll tell you a lot about what to avoid when asking.

Comment: "You're going to put a bounty on an open question? This sounds like a waste of reputation points to me. But you are certainly allowed to try it and see what happens." I was going to put a bounty on an argument making a claim about part of an open question, @mixedmath. Perhaps not so different.

Comment: This kind of page, @vonbrand? http://startswithabang.com/?p=1447

Comment: @TravellingSalesman, yes, that is an example (among many).

Comment: Did anything ever come of this? I don't see any signs of questions about open problems being asked...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I was digesting the general advice here, checking my argument for how crackpot it looks etc. It's a question about whether sequences in the Collatz conjecture can loop. I plan to post it today.

Comment: I posted a claim, asking for feedback on flaws in my argument, that only one sequence in the Collatz conjecture loops.

Comment: John Nash used to pose open questions on exams. One time, he posed a question that amounted to a disguised FLT. He reasoned that if the stigma was removed from the question, a student might actually discover a unique answer. A bit of a bratty approach, IMO. ;)

Comment: Is it common for members to vote for a question to be suspended for a reason, and then not bother checking back to see if the question has been edited to satisfy their criticism?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the scale of this website, @TravellingSalesman. There are about 80 questions put on hold every day. Every user with the required privilege can vote to close 50 questions every day. It makes no sense to require every user to check back every question they have voted to close to see if it has improved. Instead, other users (the one who happen to look at the front page at that moment, or the ones who go to the reopen review queue) will see the post and will judge if it deserves being reopened. To answer your question, "yes, it's common".

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, Najib. Whatever the scale of the website, I have to say that sounds like a design flaw to me. Perhaps people with the required privilege should be able to close a smaller number of questions each day so that they have time to take a bit more interest in whether their demands were met? Given that there seems to be no way to appeal against the rushed decisions of these overstretched people?

Comment: If you wanted to be pinged in a response, then @NajibIdrissi.